# Shinyapp.io Questions: (1) Embed code so others can share my app & (2) How many instances and active hours do I need?

Tags: shiny, web-hosting

(1) I would like to host an app on shinyapp.io and embed it in my website. I would like to allow other people to take this app (shinyapp.io url), so that they can post the app on their own website. Is there a way that I can share this easily?

(2) If I have a relatively busy website, how many instances and active hours do I need?

Thanks in advance!

C

Answer (score 1):

There is a conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/2VwEWXYJwYs) about using iframes to embed shiny apps in html documents.